# jQuery draggables jumping inside jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, dialog, draggable

I'm using jQuery draggables inside jQuery dialog to display some notes and those draggables jump around in IE8 when they are dragged from one position to another within the dialog. However, id I drag the dialog itself to the top of the page, the draggables seem to work fine. I'm assuming the draggables need to be configured a certain way to work within dialog in IE. I've tried using {iframefix : true}, {containment : 'parent'}, {containment : 'window'}, {appendTo : jQuery('#nameoftheparentdiv') } etc... to no avail. Any help is appreciated.